# Open Soft Keyboard with Specific Input Type

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm using an HTML form in WebView. I want to open specific soft keyboard when my  type is email or url. In app we can do it by specifying `android:inputType="textEmailAddress"` or `android:inputType="textUri"` in EditText.

In my scenario i do not have edit text. Well, using JavaScript Interface i'm able to call my java method whenever i focus on input type email or url in html. But i did not find any API to open soft keyboard of inputType textUri or textEmailAddress.

Does anyone knows how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have already a solution to this problem?